# Is it possible to have a setup project create a registry value without overwriting an existing one?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I know it can be done with a custom action, but can it be done without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

1. Under **Launch Conditions**, go to **Search Target Machine** and create a new **Registry Search**. This will set an MSI property (e.g. `MY_PROPERTY`) to that registry value.
2. In the **Registry** window, specify the registry key you want to create and, as the **Condition**, enter `MY_PROPERTY = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

[WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern)

The advantage is you could then use the property in UI in case you want to give the user a chance to see the existing value and then decide to change it or not.